# Peculiar Virual Function Fixes Unresolved External Symbol

Tags: c++, linker, virtual-functions

I just inherited some legacy code. Where a problem method is being called. I have two solutions at the bottom, but why does making problemMethod virtual work...

```
OtherClass::someOtherMethod() {
    // problemMethod(Manager* manager, const ConfigClass* config)
    obj->problemMethod(man, conf); // conf is not const in this file which therefore does not match the params list.
}
```

now in the obj .h and .cpp the method is of the form (I checked both cpp and h do both match).

```
    problemMethod(Manager* manager, const ConfigClass* config);
```

When trying to build it has an unresolved external in OtherClass::SomeOtherMethod, not knowing where problemMethod is.

Two solutions: change the problemMethod in the .h and .cpp and remove const. Which works and builds and runs. Or make problemMethod virtual. Why does making it virtual work? My guess is that because it is virtual it would make it delayed til runtime which would prevent the linker error and then it just figures it out later...??? The confusing part about the linker error is that visual studio when hitting F12 on that method does find it and know where it is.

Comment: Provide a minimal program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: ***The confusing part about the linker error is that visual studio when hitting F12 on that method does find it and know where it is.*** This really has nothing to do with what symbols the linker has access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

The problem was that in OtherClass.h the Config was forward declared as a struct when it is a class. It does not complain about this in vs2010 but does for vs2017